# Deduplicate files using the command line in OSX Lion

Tags: command-line, deduplication

I am using OSX 10.8.4 and would like to remove duplicate files in a single flat directory if an md5 hash matches.

I have looked up several answers but none of them work for me, I think because of differences in command syntax between terminal versions.

Things I have tried:

http://www.chriswrites.com/2012/02/how-to-find-and-delete-duplicate-files-in-mac-os-x/

[Finding and removing duplicate files in osx with a script](https://superuser.com/questions/481456/finding-and-removing-duplicate-files-in-osx-with-a-script)

and some of these:
http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3555/find-duplicate-files-based-on-size-first-then-md5-hash#comment

This approach feels closest:

```
find . -size 20 \! -type d -exec cksum {} \; | sort | tee /tmp/f.tmp | cut -f 1,2 -d ' ' | uniq -d | grep -hif - /tmp/f.tmp > duplicates.txt
```

But I get an error: `grep: -: No such file or directory`

Upon inspection, /tmp/f.tmp does exist.
The duplicates.txt file is created but is empty.

How do I deduplicate these files?

Comment: If you're not opposed to using a script, checkout dupinator, it is a python script which could accomplish this task. http://code.activestate.com/recipes/362459/

Comment: Tried this. it finds no duplicates in a test folder which has intentional duplicates. Also comment 6 notes a data-losing bug: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/362459/#c6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default on Mac OS you'll be getting BSD `grep`, while the command that you've posted is most probably for GNU `grep`.  The two versions of the tools are similar, but not identical.  This is true for other tools as well (e.g. the GNU and BSD versions of `date` behave slightly differently, too).

The issue is the `-` following the grep command. GNU `grep` interprets this as `stdin` (thus, those lines that have been identified as duplicates by `uniq -d`), while BSD `grep` is actually looking for a while called `-`; hence the error message:

```
>> find . \! -type d -exec cksum {} \; | sort | tee /tmp/f.tmp | cut -f 1,2 -d ' ' | uniq -d | grep -hif - /tmp/f.tmp
grep: -: No such file or directory
```

The same thing happens if you replace the `-` with another name that doesn't match any files:

```
>> find . \! -type d -exec cksum {} \; | sort | tee /tmp/f.tmp | cut -f 1,2 -d ' ' | uniq -d | grep -hif unknown-file /tmp/f.tmp
grep: unknown-file: No such file or directory
```

You can bash's [process substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) to feed the stdout from everything up to the `uniq` to `grep` as a file, e.g. (I've dropped the size criterion in this example, but the rest is the same):

```
>> grep -hif <(find . \! -type d -exec cksum {} \; | sort | tee /tmp/f.tmp | cut -f 1,2 -d ' ' | uniq -d) /tmp/f.tmp
4192268874 275 ./foo/META-INF/leiningen/foo/foo/project.clj
4192268874 275 ./foo/project.clj
```

Answer (score 5):

Finding duplicates based on hashkey works well and is very fast. I use the following code often. If you are running this on a Mac and face any issues, install GNU tools and use the second version.

## Linux

> find -not -empty -type f -printf "%s\n" | sort -rn | uniq -d | xargs -I{} -n1 find -type f -size {}c -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum | sort | uniq -w32 --all-repeated=separate

## Mac version

> gfind -not -empty -type f -printf "%s\n" | sort -rn | guniq -d | xargs -I{} -n1 find -type f -size {}c -print0 | xargs -0 gmd5sum | sort | guniq -w32 --all-repeated=separate

Comment: Thanks, that helped! The `uniq -w32` is really the missing piece of the puzzle--without partial line matching, finding duplicates is significantly harder (especially in a shell language).